# Vagrant multi machine not running global settings

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I am very new to vagrant so apologies in advance for what I am sure is really obvious.

I am trying to write a vagrant file to support multiple machines. As a test I started with a very basic file:

```
Vagrant::configure("2") do |config|
    # Use a standard box
    config.vm.box = 'precise64'
    config.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box'

    # Set the Timezone to something useful
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo \"Europe/London\" | sudo tee /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata"

    # Update the servers
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get update --fix-missing"
end
```

This worked as expected, timezone set, updates run. So, I then went ahead with the following:

```
Vagrant::configure("2") do |config|
    # Use a standard box
    config.vm.box = 'precise64'
    config.vm.box_url = 'http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box'

    # Set the Timezone to something useful
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "echo \"Europe/London\" | sudo tee /etc/timezone && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata"

    # Update the servers
    config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get update --fix-missing"

    config.vm.define :lamp do |lamp|
        lamp.vm.hostname = "lamp.local"
        lamp.vm.network :private_network, ip: "33.33.33.10"
        #lamp.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "apt-get update --fix-missing"
    end

end
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. The box came up fine, but timezone not set, updates not run or ip set. the commented line for apt-get update was also tried with no luck.
Must be something simple I am sure. Through reading the documentation, global settings should also be applied.. I guess I need to understand why they arent.
Thanks
Adam

Comment: You are using the same private network settings (ip) for multiple Vagrant VM instances, this could cause IP conflicts. How many instances did you spin up with this Vagrantfile?

Comment: Hi Terry. No, that ip is specific to the "lamp" box - only 1 will be spun up.

Comment: Enable debugging by `VAGRANT_LOG=debug vagrant up` to see more output.

Comment: There aren't any errors. It just is not running the config.vm.provision commands when using config.vm.define

Comment: I just ran your `Vagrantfile` and everything worked as expected... what version of Vagrant are you using?

Comment: Tested with Vagrant 1.3.4 + VirtualBox 4.2.18, it works.

Answer (score 1):

With [Vagrant 1.3.0](https://github.com/10up/varying-vagrant-vagrants/issues/148), `vagrant up` no longer does provisioning after the first (if you use `vagrant halt` or `vagrant reload`).

So you may want to try doing `vagrant destroy` before `vagrant up` again. There was a bug in [1.3.2](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2285) that didn't make `vagrant destroy` do reprovisioning, but fixed in the next version (1.3.3).

Or you may try executing it manually `vagrant provision` or `vagrant up --provision`.